# Spring Rest MultiModule Project has ClassCastException in requestMappingHandlerMapping()

Tags: rest, spring-boot, classcastexception, multi-module

I am facing following issue. I have a multi module project for which I now want to design a Rest-Module for using Spring-Hateoas.

The underlaying modules works as expected. The modules are organized like follows:

- app

  - rest
  - business
  - backend

All modules are build by spring-boot in current version 1.1.9.RELEASE.

When I start the Integration-Test as well runable Application class I get the stacktrace you find below. That stacktrace just come when I integrate the business module in application class of rest module.

====

TESTCLASS

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = ApplicationRest.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ActiveProfiles("localhost")
public class ApplicationRestTest {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

===

CONFIGURATION CLASS OF REST MODULE => 
RUNNING THAT CLASS ONLY WORKS WHEN COMMENTING @IMPORT!!!

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Import(ApplicationBusiness.class) // WORKS WHEN COMMENTING THAT LINE!!!
@PropertySource({ "classpath:/config/application-localhost.properties" })
public class ApplicationRest {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApplicationRest.class, args);
    }
}
```

===

CONFIGURATION OF BUSINESS MODULE => 
RUNNING THAT CLASS WORKS!!!

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@Import(Application.class)
@PropertySource({ "classpath:/config/application-localhost.properties" })
public class ApplicationBusiness {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApplicationBusiness.class, args);
    }
}
```

===

CONFIGURATION OF BACKEND MODULE => 
RUNNING THAT CLASS WORKS

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableJpaRepositories
@ImportResource("classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext-*.xml")
public class Application {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final ConfigurableApplicationContext context =    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

        final ContractService service = context.getBean(ContractService.class);
        service.countAllContracts();

        context.close();
    }
}
```

====

STACKTRACE

```
CONSOLE OUTPUT OF MODULES BACKEND AND BUSINESS ARE OKAY

....

CONSOLE OUTPUT REST MODULE STARTS HERE ...

2014-11-15 13:39:21.125  INFO 7988 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2014-11-15 13:39:21.346  WARN 7988 --- [           main] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt

2014-11-15 13:20:13.722 ERROR 3472 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@29ae2517] to prepare test instance [at.compax.bbsng.app.rest.ApplicationRestTest@7a78d2aa]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:103)
at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:98)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:161)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:101)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:331)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:213)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:292)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:233)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:87)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:176)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.requestMappingHandlerMapping()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy130 cannot be cast to org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:597)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:990)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:706)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
at org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader.loadContext(SpringApplicationContextLoader.java:107)
at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:69)
at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:95)
... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.requestMappingHandlerMapping()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy130 cannot be cast to org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:188)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:586)
... 41 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy130 cannot be cast to org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService
at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9d0e5a2e.mvcConversionService(<generated>)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.getInterceptors(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:230)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.requestMappingHandlerMapping(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:197)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9d0e5a2e.CGLIB$requestMappingHandlerMapping$17(<generated>)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9d0e5a2e$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c90faea7.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:312)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9d0e5a2e.requestMappingHandlerMapping(<generated>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:166)
... 42 common frames omitted
```

============

That Issues happens when I add the following dependency to the classpath:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

When removing it, then it does not complain.

===============

Starting in Debug-Mode prints out following classpath dependencies, maybe that helps:

```
2014-11-15 16:18:48.758  INFO 8896 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/C:/Development/Projekte/bbsng/trunk/app/rest/target/classes/, file:/C:/Development/Projekte/bbsng/trunk/app/business/target/classes/, file:/C:/Development/Projekte/bbsng/trunk/app/backend/target/classes/, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/1.1.9.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-1.1.9.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/1.1.9.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-aop-1.1.9.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjrt/1.8.4/aspectjrt-1.8.4.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.8.4/aspectjweaver-1.8.4.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/1.1.9.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.1.9.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/4.0.8.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-jdbc/7.0.56/tomcat-jdbc-7.0.56.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-juli/7.0.56/tomcat-juli-7.0.56.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.0.8.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-orm/4.0.8.RELEASE/spring-orm-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jpa/1.6.4.RELEASE/spring-data-jpa-1.6.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/1.8.4.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aspects/4.0.8.RELEASE/spring-aspects-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/org/postgresql/postgresql/9.3-1102-jdbc41/postgresql-9.3-1102-jdbc41.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/org/hsqldb/hsqldb/2.3.2/hsqldb-2.3.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.1/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp/1.4/commons-dbcp-1.4.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/commons-pool/commons-pool/1.6/commons-pool-1.6.jar, file:/C:/Development/Projekte/bbsng/trunk/app/domain/target/classes/, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/4.3.6.Final/hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.6.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging-annotations/1.2.0.Beta1/jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.6.Final/hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jandex/1.1.0.Final/jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.0.b2/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/4.0.5.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/transaction/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec/1.0.0.Final/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.18.1-GA/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/com/mysema/querydsl/querydsl-jpa/3.4.3/querydsl-jpa-3.4.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/com/mysema/querydsl/querydsl-core/3.4.3/querydsl-core-3.4.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/14.0/guava-14.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9/jsr305-1.3.9.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/com/mysema/commons/mysema-commons-lang/0.2.4/mysema-commons-lang-0.2.4.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/com/infradna/tool/bridge-method-annotation/1.13/bridge-method-annotation-1.13.jar, file:/C:/Development/Projekte/bbsng/trunk/app/log/target/classes/, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjtools/1.8.4/aspectjtools-1.8.4.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.1.9.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.1.9.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.1.9.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.1.9.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.1.9.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.1.9.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.1.9.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.1.9.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.7/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.7/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.7/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.2/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.2/logback-core-1.1.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.13/snakeyaml-1.13.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/org/projectlombok/lombok/1.14.8/lombok-1.14.8.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-collections4/4.0/commons-collections4-4.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.3.2/commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/joda-time/joda-time/2.3/joda-time-2.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator/1.1.9.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-actuator-1.1.9.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-actuator/1.1.9.RELEASE/spring-boot-actuator-1.1.9.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.0.8.RELEASE/spring-core-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.1.9.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-1.1.9.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.1.9.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.1.9.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/7.0.56/tomcat-embed-core-7.0.56.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/7.0.56/tomcat-embed-el-7.0.56.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli/7.0.56/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-7.0.56.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/7.0.56/tomcat-embed-websocket-7.0.56.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.0.3.Final/hibernate-validator-5.0.3.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.1.1.GA/jboss-logging-3.1.1.GA.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.0.0/classmate-1.0.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.0.8.RELEASE/spring-web-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.0.8.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.0.8.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/org/springframework/hateoas/spring-hateoas/0.16.0.RELEASE/spring-hateoas-0.16.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.0.8.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.0.8.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.0.8.RELEASE/spring-context-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/org/objenesis/objenesis/2.1/objenesis-2.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.7/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/org/springframework/plugin/spring-plugin-core/1.1.0.RELEASE/spring-plugin-core-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.3.4/jackson-databind-2.3.4.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.3.4/jackson-annotations-2.3.4.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.3.4/jackson-core-2.3.4.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/com/jayway/jsonpath/json-path/0.9.1/json-path-0.9.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/hegnerM/.m2/repository/net/minidev/json-smart/1.2/json-smart-1.2.jar]
```

Comment: Post the configuration class. My guess is you are enabling/creating proxies there leading to proxies of proxies.

Comment: I added Config Classes of Rest-, Business- and Backend-Module

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got the problem, but I really don't know why this is a problem or is it a spring bug.

I am using a module for Business-Method Logging, what I have centralized as aspect. This works with the modules backend and business, it just start that exception behavior when I use spring-mvc with spring-boot.

As you seen above my module backend has annotation @ImportResource("classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext-*.xml"), so that spring can find the xml-config file what includes following (mentioned I use that xml-file for years to log service logger without any problems):

```
<bean id="serviceLogger" class="at.compax.bbsng.app.log.service.ServiceLogger" />

<aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
    <aop:include name="serviceLogger" />
</aop:aspectj-autoproxy>

<!-- Trace all service methods -->
<bean id="debugInterceptor" class="org.springframework.aop.interceptor.DebugInterceptor">
    <property name="useDynamicLogger" value="true" />
    <property name="hideProxyClassNames" value="true" />
</bean>

<!-- Time-Logger -->
<bean id="performanceMonitorInterceptor"
    class="org.springframework.aop.interceptor.PerformanceMonitorInterceptor">
    <property name="useDynamicLogger" value="true" />
</bean>

<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="daoPointcut" expression="execution(* *..*Repository+.*(..))" />
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="debugInterceptor" pointcut-ref="daoPointcut" />
</aop:config>

<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="servicePointcut" expression="execution(* *..*Service+.*(..))" />
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="performanceMonitorInterceptor"
        pointcut-ref="servicePointcut" />
</aop:config>
```

I don't know why spring-boot-mvc has problem with that and why. Does it have problem with annotation for importing xml-files or does it have problems with aspects. But I guess I will find out and I will report.

If someone knows what is the problem, please don't hesiate to post.

=======

As mentioned spring-web-starter seems to have problem when using aspect. But thats really stupid, it always worked when doing multi-module-project without spring-boot. If nobody knows answer on it, I guess it is a spring bug and I will create jira ticket. Ideas are welcome....

Comment: Spring Boot already enables proxies, I suspect it still works when you remove the `<aop:aspect-autoproxy />`. I also suggest merging the `<aop:config />` blocks into a single one and instead of using the `PerformanceMonitorInterceptor` I suggest you write something that taps into the metrics support provided by Spring Boot. The major issue is that you have multiple proxy mechanisms in place leading to proxies of proxies.

Answer (score 0):

I regenerated `serialVersionUID` after changed of Class properties, and that is works for me.